# Remove duplicate elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to figure out how to remove duplicates in a list of lists in a way that if the element is already present in any list I want it not to be added again.

Here is the whole

```
def listeAmis(n) : 
    liste = []
    print("Rentrez un numéro d'un ami de ",n)
    a = 0
    while a!="na": 
        a=input("tapez 'na' s'il n'y a pas d'autres amis")
        liste.append(a) 
    last = int(len(liste)-1)
    del liste[last]
    return liste



def initReseau(n) : 
    i = 0
    listeR = []
    while i<n : 
        listeR.append(listeAmis(i))
        i = i+1
    return listeR

def ami(r,i,j) : 
    if j in r[i] and i in r[j]: 
        return True
    else : 
        return False

def groupeAmis(r,i) : 
    groupe = [i]
    a = 0
    while a < n-1 :  
        res = all(ami(r,elem,a) for elem in groupe)
        if res :
            groupe.append(a)
        a=a+1
    return groupe


def groupeAmisPartition(r) : 
    liste=[]
    for i in range(0,n) : 
        T = groupeAmis(r,i)
        liste.append(T)
    return liste




n = 8
r = [[2, 3], [3, 5], [0, 3, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [3, 7],[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5]]
groupeAmisPartition(r)
```

Here is what I get :

```
[[0, 2, 3],[1, 3, 5],[2, 0, 3],[3, 0, 2],[4, 3],[5, 1, 3],[6, 2, 3],[7, 2]]
```

Here is what I want :

```
[[0,2,3],[1,5],[4,7],[6]]
```

thanks

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: Is r the input? If so why is there a 0 in the expected output's first list [0,2,3]

Comment: all the inner lists are sorted ?

Comment: you are not using `initReseau` function ?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on your text description of the problem.

Try this (explanation in code comment):

```
r = [[2, 3], [3, 5], [0, 3, 6, 7], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [3, 7],[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5]]
done= []
big_new_lst = []
# for items in initial list
for i in r:
    # initialize empty "small list"
    new_lst = []
    # for item in list in initial list
    for c in i:
        # if item is not in our done list
        if c not in done:
            #add it to our done list
            done.append(c)
            # add it to our new small list
            new_lst.append(c)
    # add the small list to the big list if it's not empty
    if new_lst:
        big_new_lst.append(new_lst)

print (big_new_lst)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [5], [0, 6, 7], [1, 4]]
```

Comment: @kederrac That's why I said My answer is based on your text description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps even if it is not the output expected
Actually this is is an exercise about a social network.
r is the network describing this way r[i] are all the friends of person i.
The question is to determine "group of friends" so that all lists in a list represent persons that are all friends.

Comment: but with the constraint that a person [i] can't be in two different groups of friends..

Answer (score 0):

With Thaer's code I got this, still not the one expected but almost :

```
def groupeAmisPartition(r) : 
    liste=[]
    for i in range(0,n) : 
        T = groupeAmis(r,i)
        liste.append(T)
    done= []
    big_new_lst = []
    for i in liste:
        new_lst = []
        for c in i:
            if c not in done:
                done.append(c)
                new_lst.append(c)
        if new_lst:
            big_new_lst.append(new_lst)
    return big_new_lst
```

Output :

```
[[0, 2, 3], [1, 5], [4], [6], [7]]
```

Comment: 4 and 7 are friends and they have not been in a group of friends before so they should be a group of friends [4,7]